# Unexpected token # in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to parse a json string and I'm getting the error:

```
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 13
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:6

Follows the code:

    JSON.parse("{\"chars\":\" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿıŁłŒœŠšŸŽžƒˆˇˉ˘˙˚˛˜˝ΔΩμπ‐–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™Ω∂∆∏∑−∕∙√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ}")
```

Comment: That is not a valid json string

Comment: Your escaping is wrong.  The `\"` before `#` is being interpreted as the end of the string.

Comment: @Jerodev I know that is not a valid json string. My problem is understanding why.

Comment: @Joe Thank you. Know I see the problem

Comment: How are you getting invalid JSON in the first place? You should never try to create JSON by hand, always use a library function to do it.

Comment: @Barmar This is just a part of my problem. My problem is to complex to be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your escaping. You have to escape the double quotes as well as the backslash in the characters value. I removed the second backslash from within the square brackets as this also resulted in a parse error.

Also, to simplify escaping the value to pass to JSON.parse, use JSON.stringify on an object with chars value rather than a constructed string.
See: [JSON Stringify on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

The following restructuring of the characters value works:

```
var charObj = {chars: " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿıŁłŒœŠšŸŽžƒˆˇˉ˘˙˚˛˜˝ΔΩμπ‐–—‘’‚“”„†‡•…‰‹›⁄€™Ω∂∆∏∑−∕∙√∞∫≈≠≤≥◊ﬁﬂ"};
```

JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(charObj));